# Android AlertDialog.Builder with Radiobutton and Spinner

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Following code shows the radio-button with AlertDialog builder. I was trying to figure out is it possible to add a Spinner below the radio-button ?  Is this supported or AlertDialog can be used either for radio-button or Spinner but not both?

```
      // listItems has values "z","y","x" 
       final CharSequence[] avail_types = listItems.toArray(new CharSequence[listItems.size()]);

       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(" Select your choice ");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(avail_types, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
               selected_item = item;
            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do_yes()
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: You have to customize the alert dialog content for showing both spinner and radio button. Using setSingleChoiceItems() will not work

Comment: thanks for the comment. Will read about customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying to figure out is it possible to add a Spinner below the
>   radio-button ?

No, with default implementation of `setSingleChoiceItems` method it's not possible to add other Views in AlertDialog layout.

> Is this supported or AlertDialog can be used either for radio-button
>   or Spinner but not both?

No,but you can create a custom `AlertDialog` using custom layout for it with `ListView` and ListView row layout contain `RadioButton` and `Spinner` both.

**EDIT:**

See following tutorial for creating AlertDialog with custom layout:

[Create AlertDialog with Custom Layout using XML Layout](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/create-alertdialog-with-custom-layout-using-xml-layout/)

Comment: thanks for the answer and URL. Will create a custom layout.